# How to initWithNib to a derived subclass

Tags: ios, uiview, uitableview, nib

I've got the following class hierarchy:

```
FruitCell : UITableViewCell (with associated .xib)
    ----------------------------
   |                            |
BananaCell : FruitCell       PeachCell : FruitCell
```

How do I init FruitCell.xib but ensure it is kindOfClass PeachCell.m or BananaCell.m without having 2 copies of FruitCell.xib? Right now the .view in FruitCell.xib is of class FruitCell.

I'm not sure what to do other than try assign every IBOutlet from my FruitCell instance to my BananaCell or PeachCell but then the IBAction's aren't handled.

========EDIT
Just to add, this is how I'm loading the nib and finding the right class

```
NSArray *topLevelObjects = [bundle loadNibNamed: nibNameOrNil owner: self options:nil];
for (id object in topLevelObjects) {
    if ([object isKindOfClass: [FruitCell class]]) {
        // need to somehow change before loadNibNamed this to Banana or Peach
        return object;
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest one of the following options:

1) Have two copies of FruitCell.xib (this is really not that bad)

2) Instead of FruitCell.xib, create your PeachCell and BananaCell instances in code and load a FruitCellContents.xib which just contains a subview you can add to your already-created cell's contentView.

3) This is more complex perhaps not worth the trouble, but you can get what you want by keeping your current FruitCell.xib and overriding `initWithCoder:` in your FruitCell class to return an instance of either a BananaCell or PeachCell instead. Something like:

```
static Class substituteClass;
+ (void)prepareToLoadWithClass:(Class)c {
   substituteClass = c;
}

- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder {
    if (substituteClass) { 
        substituteClass = Nil; // because the next line will call this method again as its superclass
        self = [[substituteClass alloc] initWithCoder:aCoder];
    } else {
        self = [super initWithCoder:aCoder];
    }
    return self;
}
```

The catch is deciding which class to initialize there. I don't really have an idea better than a global or thread-local that you set before loading the nib and clear afterwards. So, you'd call `[FruitCell prepareToLoadWithClass:[PeachCell class]]` first, then load the nib.

Comment: Yeah the root of the issue is that I have an (IBAction) method in my FruitCell class that I want to override. I'm aware of a few messy things I can do but it would be nice to just load a nib against a derived sub class :(

Comment: OK. I have one more suggestion.

Comment: @MikeS Take a look now.

Comment: See my edit... Will that change my Custom Class property set in IB from FruitCell for my custom UITableViewCell to the derived instance?

Comment: @JesseRusak : The original question asks for an approach that should be without using two copies of FruitCell.xib. (How do I init FruitCell.xib but ensure it is kindOfClass PeachCell.m or BananaCell.m without having 2 copies of FruitCell.xib?)

Comment: @BalramTiwari Yes; I have given two options other than that one, as well as asserting that having two xibs is actually not that bad. I've edited my question to make this more clear, thanks.

Comment: @MikeS Yes, it will change the class of the loaded FruitCell to the subclass you specify by calling `prepareToLoadWithClass:` before loading the nib. Note that as currently written it will only work for the first instance of FruitCell in your nib, but I assume you only have one instance in there.

Comment: I've tried it and I get this error printed to NSLog "*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'This coder requires that replaced objects be returned from initWithCoder:'"

Comment: Oh, damn, sorry. I just re-read the docs and `initWithCoder:` says you can't pull the trick I suggested. You could return the object from `awakeAfterUsingCoder:` instead, but you'd have to copy over anything set on `self` to the new object first.

Comment: So assign every IBOutlet property and (somehow) redirect all IBActions to the new instance?

Comment: Yes; you can iterate through your control's actions with `allTargets` and `allControlEvents` and `actionsForTarget:forControlEvent` and hook those up from your new view well. I think this is a lot more work than either of the other options.